# is possibile to fork the bitcoin blockchain and change it checking if the pow is created from a clean energy?

Tags: blockchain-fork, proof-of-work

is possible to Clone the Bitcoin blockchain and in the calculation, it does for the difficulty, instead of the global hash power given by the ASICs, put it the global production of clean energy connected to the grid, hen second step would be to reward not by performing a calculation but .. lottery? I don't know one of the methods already used maybe .. the more energy you produce the more chances you have of winning and A connected clamp meter maybe to check if it's clean energy?

I don't know if it possible, i hope that someone has an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **is possibile to fork the bitcoin blockchain and change it checking if the pow is created from a clean energy?**

No.

It isn't possible because there's no way for other nodes to check the source of energy used by an anonymous member of an anonymous mining pool.

> **A connected clamp meter maybe to check if it's clean energy?**

A clamp meter measures current, it can't tell you anything about the power source of the generators that provide that current.

Other nodes have no access to that clamp meter and cannot tell if it is accurate.

Remember that a fundamental part of a *peer to peer* cryptocurrency that is like Bitcoin is that nobody has to trust what miners tell them.

---

At the very least, it is an immense job to make anything of this sort bulletproof enough to be usable.

Comment: got it, thank u very much